# Is it possible to refer self property type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to make some logger like below code.

Is it possible to change `unknown` type to `specific` type?

```js
type Poo = {
  prop1: 1 | 2 | 3;
  prop2: "a" | "b" | "c";
}

type Log<T> = {
  prop: keyof T;
  prev: unknown; // Todo
  cur: unknown; // Todo
}

const pooLogger: Log<Poo>[] = [];

const log: Log<Poo> = {
  prop: "prop1",
  prev: "a", // This line must cause error message like "a" is not 1 | 2 | 3
  cur: 1
}

pooLogger.push(log)
```

`T[Log<T>["prop"]]` is `1 | 2 | 3 | "a" | "b" | "c"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [conditional type to distribute the union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) of `T`'s properties:

```
type Log<T, P extends keyof T = keyof T> = P extends keyof T ?
  {prop: P; prev: T[P]; cur: unknown;} :
  never
```

`Log<Poo>` will be `{prop: 'prop1', prev: 1|2|3} | {prop: 'prop2', prev: 'a'|'b'|'c'}`